# Redis-pubsub in nodeJs, do "HGET" command

Tags: ruby, node.js, redis, publish-subscribe

I want to get hash data in the redis server from nodeJs server

i have this script in the ruby

```
$redis.hset("token:test", 'user_id', 12)
```

how I can get 'token:test' value in the NodeJs server
I've try

```
var pubsub = redis.createClient();
pubsub.hget("token:test",'user_id');
```

but it say undifined  :(

can anyone help me??

Comment: I think its solved

With

pubsub.hget("token:test",'user_id', function(err, data){console.log(data)});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since node.js and it's modules are [evented and non-blocking](http://code.danyork.com/2011/01/25/node-js-doctors-offices-and-fast-food-restaurants-understanding-event-driven-programming/) by it's nature, you should pass callback as the third parameter when you want to get the result of `hget` command.

```
redisClient.hget("myKey", "myField", function(err, obj) {
    // in case of error
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    // do something with returned object
    ...
});
```